# Unreasonable CPU consumption for server build with nographics

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, graphics, profiling, cpu

I have built my game in server mode on Mac OS and attached profiler to it. In profiler I can see unreasonable high cpu load.

1. Other scripts take a lot of cpu time. How can this be optimized?
   [image: screenshot]
2. Vsync takes a lot of time otherwise. How can it be since I have disabled VSync, built as server, run with -nographics and even removed cameras and UI?
   [image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you expect it to do other than sleep if you tell it to run at 30 fps and there's not enough work to keep it busy for 33 ms every frame?

Comment: First of all enable `DeepProfile` otherwise you can't bday anyway what exactly eats your performance

Comment: @Sunius I would assume that in server mode CPU is NOT busy by anything. because CPU time for servers dictates costs. if nothing needs to be done, then let CPU do other stuff. At least it sounds logical to me :)

Comment: @Daily Dreamer Unity's profiler does not measure the CPU busy time. It measures wall clock. It accounts for both busy time and idle time. WaitForTargetFPS is essentially sleeping and thus indicates that Unity ISN'T using the CPU during that time.

Comment: @Sunius I was hoping on that too. However, I deployed my server in Google Cloud and measured resources consumption there. CPU usage during wait for players period is still 30-40ms. No other scripts were running in parallel (profiler confirms that).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your game is doing in terms of calculations from custom scripts, but if its not just an empty project, then i dont see why 33ms is unreasonable. Check your servers specs maybe? Also VSync just idles for a need amount of time to reach the fixed target FPS, meaning its not actually under load, even though the profiler is showing it as a big lump of color. Think of it more as headroom - how much processing you can still do per frame and have your target FPS.

Comment: For these particular snapshots my server is waiting for clients to connect.
As for 33ms. Assuming that we pay for cloud resources, why should we pay for nothing? 10 servers mean 330ms. 30 servers mean 990. it is almost one core for servers doing nothing and just waiting for clients to join.